# Swift Mailer and Symfony2 - no mail in the spool

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Cross-posted from the official Swift Mailer group....

I'm trying to send emails using the Swift Mailer bundle and a file spool, but when I tell the console to send the mail, it tells me there are 0 messages in the spool.  Is the spool supposed to be created by Swift Mailer automatically, or do I need to manually create a file?  Because I don't see a spool file anywhere.

My config.yml:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: sendmail
    host:      /usr/bin/sendmail
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:
        type: file
        path: "%kernel.root_dir%/spool"
```

How I'm sending the mail:

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name:'))
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Email Address:'))
        ->add('subject', 'text', array('label' => 'Subject:'))
        ->add('message', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Message:'))
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        $data = $form->getData();

        if (!empty($data['name'])) {
            $data['message'] = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $data['message']);

            $emailValidator = new Email();
            $emailValidator->message = "Invalid email address";

            $error = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($data['email'], $emailValidator);

            if (count($error) == 0) {
                $mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject($data['subject'])
                    ->setFrom('mail@mysite.com')
                    ->setTo('me@myrealaddress.com')
                    ->setBody($data['message']);

                $this->get('mailer')->send($mail);

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_success'));
            } else {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_failure'));
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  According to the Symfony docs, this should be working.

Comment: What if you change the spool conf to be `path:             "%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool"`? (don't forget to clear the cache after)

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick!  Kinda wish the docs had that rather than `"%kernel.root_dir%/spool"`.  Make it an answer and I'll upvote/mark as solved.

Comment: I would like to make sure what your problem was: if you put back `%kernel.root_dir%/spool` and manually create the directory in your Symfony root folder and give the user who runs your web server full rights does it work?

Comment: I have tested and it seems to really be a permission problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a standard installation, `path: "%kernel.root_dir%/spool"` is equivalent to `app/spool` and to create and write inside this directory, the user running your web server needs the specific permissions.

However, if you don't want to change the permissions on your directory, you can always use the `cache` folder with the following configuration:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: sendmail
    host:      /usr/bin/sendmail
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:
        type: file
        path: "%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool"
```

**Please note** that by doing so, you have to be really careful when you clear your cache because if you have unsent emails, they will vanish with the other cache files.

Comment: Apologies for not replying to your previous suggestion.  I'll have to figure out the permissions.  I'm on a shared host, so my options are a bit limited.

Comment: Huh... a closer look tells me that a spool directory *was* created in app (`app/spool`) last night during my initial tests.  But for some reason, no emails were sent to it....  Hmmm.  More testing needed, I guess.  I'd really like it so the spool **isn't** in my cache, if I can help it.

Comment: How do you proceed to setup the permissions on your `app/cache` folder? Can you do the same on the `app/spool` one?

Comment: And now the spool in `app/spool` is working fine. O_o  I have the feeling that, in my haste last night, I forgot to set the `--env=prod` flag in my tests.  I double-checked the 'proper' spool after nuking the one in the cache, and verified there **was** a message in it, and I **was** able to send it via the console.  So, it looks like it's all working.  Thanks for your help! :)